# Refresh user control instance inside a panel when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have these codes in my `Mainform` that when I click on a `picturebox`, a `user control` then loads in the a panel.

My problem is the `datagridviews` inside other controls doesn't get updated. When I make transactions in other `user controls` that affects other `user controls`.

What I want now is to automatically update those `gridviews` by refreshing the `user control` when their associated `button` is `clicked`.

```
private void pictureBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel2.Controls.Add(UCCustomer.Instance);
    UCCustomer.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    UCCustomer.Instance.BringToFront();
    lblMenu.Text = "Customer Management";
}

private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel2.Controls.Add(UCDelivery.Instance);
    UCDelivery.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    UCDelivery.Instance.BringToFront();
    lblMenu.Text = "Delivery Management";
}

private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel2.Controls.Add(UCReport.Instance);
    UCReport.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    UCReport.Instance.BringToFront();
    lblMenu.Text = "Reports";
}
```

Here's an example on how I declared the instance for a user control. This is in the same format as other user controls.

```
private static UCCustomer _instance;
public static UCCustomer Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_instance == null)
            _instance = new UCCustomer();
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more details? I get confuse by so many `user control`, and also I can't see where is the `DataGridView` you have mentioned.

Comment: What I wanna do is I want to refresh user controls when I click it back and forth.